# Application unfortunately closed on xperia p mobile with api level 14

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, sony-xperia

When i am debugging my application on emulator which is of api level 14(4.0) the application is working fine, but when i am debugging same application on xperia p api level 14(4.0.4)) application has stopped unfortunately, and same application debugging on Samsung duos its working properly, application is working fine with emulator and samsung mobile af api level 14 but why its unfortunately stopped on xperia p with api level 14?

Please help me to understand this issue.

Below is the **log**:

```
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:591)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:599)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:336)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:828)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2097)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
11-09 13:22:30.678: E/AndroidRuntime(7456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```